# Can't access jQuery function in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-events

Why am I getting the `ReferenceError`:

> manualEntry is not defined error,

when using the following within Wordpress?

```
<a href="#" onclick="manualEntry()">hide</a>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
         function manualEntry() {
              $("#details").hide();
         }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The function `manualEntry` is _private_ to the `ready` callback. Move it outside of `ready` to make it **global**

Comment: I'd suggest to use jQuery's `on()` to bind events. `jQuery('anchor selector').on('click', function() { jQuery('#details').hide(); });`

Comment: But if I move it outside I get '$ is not a function'

Comment: Use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: Is there a way of using $ not jQuery?

Comment: `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();`

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="my_class" href="#">hide</a>

<script>
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $( ".my_class" ).click(function( event ) {
             event.preventDefault();
             $("#details").hide();
         });
    });
</script>
```